# Upgraded to Windows 8.1 and now I need to tap touchscreen before it responds to an edge swipe

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen

My problem:

I upgraded my Acer V5-571P-6609 touch screen laptop to Windows 8.1 and the touch screen is responding in a weird way: Say you wish to edge swipe form the right to bring up the charms. The first attempt will fail, and second attempt will succeed.

In experimenting, I found that one needs to tap or touch the touchscreen first and then perform the touchscreen action one wants within about 5 seconds.

Perhaps a driver needs to be updated, but the only touch screen driver I've found (HID-compliant touch screen) seems to be up-to-date.

Has anyone else experienced this and/or know of a solution?

Comment: You are indeed correct.  You need to wait for Acer to supply an updated drier for the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks to rosustefan on the Acer support forums. Quoting his answer:

> PROBLEM SOLVED WITH TOUCHSCREEN!   Go to Device Manager and look at
>   the Human Interface Devices. There will be some USB devices that end
>   up being the touchscreen. If you change the power options on those so
>   they don't turn off to save power the problem should be fixed.

His answer applied to the Acer Aspire S7-391 so this solution likely applies to other Acer touch screen laptops.